# What are the types for { dispatch, commit } in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, flowtype, vuex

I got vujes typescript project and in vuex store i got something like:

```
async getUserProfile ({ dispatch, commit }: any) {}
```

Well i dont want `any` because that suck and you dont have help/autocomplete in editor. I found this `import { Dispatch, Commit } from "vuex";` but how to pass that info to `{ dispatch, commit }: any`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You use `ActionContext<S, R>`, like Vuex does:

```
getUserProfile( context: ActionContext<S, R>) {}
```

Where `S` is the `State` and `R` is the `RootState`.

Then you call `dispatch` and `commit` off of the context:

```
 context.dispatch('action')
 context.commit('mutation')
```

Comment: Is there any documentation I can refer to?

Answer (score 17):

You can check out available vuex types in this file:

`node_modules/vuex/types/index.d.ts`

// line 49 :

```
export interface Commit {
  (type: string, payload?: any, options?: CommitOptions): void;
  <P extends Payload>(payloadWithType: P, options?: CommitOptions): void;
}
```

you can import and use that instead of ActionContext like so:

```
import { Commit } from 'vuex';

const actions = {
    loadUser ({ commit }: { commit: Commit }, user: any) {
        commit('setUser', user);
    },

    ...
};
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 5):

You can still destructure the context object if you'd like.

```js
import { ActionContext } from 'vuex';
import { RootState } from './types';

const actions = {
    // destructured
    loadUser ({ commit }: ActionContext<RootState, RootState>, user: any) {
        commit('setUser', user);
    },

    // not destructured
    loadUser (context: ActionContext<RootState, RootState>, user: any) {
        context.commit('setUser', user);
    },
};
```

Comment: ActionContext signature is `ActionContext<S, R>` which means first argument is module state and second is root state

Answer (score 3):

You can just import Commit type from vuex.

```
import { Commit } from "vuex";
```

and use in actions like this:

```
changeNumber({ commit }: { commit: Commit }, new_number: number) {
  commit("setNewNumber", new_number);
}
```